# handling click of Search suggestion from firebase in material search view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using material search view.What I'm doing is showing all the locations as suggestions, what I'm trying to do is when a suggestion is clicked, it reads its corresponding longitude and latitude from firebase database and show that location on map but when i click a suggestion, nothing happens.

**.Java** :

```
@Override

 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {

String searchView = materialSearchView.toString(); 
mLocations=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
getReference("Locations_Information");

mLocations.child("locationTitle").equalTo(searchView).
addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        LocationInformation locationInformation = s.getValue(LocationInformation.class);
                        LatLng location = new LatLng(locationInformation.latitude, locationInformation.longitude);

                        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 18);

                        mMap.animateCamera(update);

                        materialSearchView.clearSuggestions();

                        materialSearchView.closeSearch();
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
```

[My Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwKeP.png)

[image]

Comment: Is your `onDataChange` even triggered?

Comment: no, i don't know why is it happening.. there is no error

Comment: can you plz explain more??

Comment: Does `databaseError` provide any informations?

Comment: Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "locationTitle"' at Locations_Information to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance